# Программа GREP и регулярные выражения

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, joomla, cms, grep

Всем привет, у меня возникла задача:

Есть 3000 файлов `.html` в которых содержится по одному описанию товара. Нужно в каждом файле вытащить это описание. Пытаюсь сделать с помощью регулярных выражений.

Я сделал:
Например, хочу убрать тег и все его содержимое `<title>.*?</title>`. Это получается.

Но у меня не получается:
Убрать таким же способом `<head>.*?</head>`. В чем причина?

И если вам не сложно, пожалуйста, напишите регулярное выражение, что бы оставалось только то что в <p></p>.

Comment: @Антон Худайбердин, пожалуйста, приведите пример вашего регулярного выражения.

Comment: <p>(.*?)</p>

Answer (score 2):

Оно не будет работать, так как . сопоставляется с любым символом, кроме перевода строки. а у Вас тег head открывается и закрывается в разных строках. Для этого можно применить хак.

```
grep -Pzoa '(?s)<head>.*?</head>' *.html
```

суть. 
`-P` включает перловые регулярки, Они просто более понятны для меня.
`-z` заменяет все переводы строк на нулевой символ. Таким образом весь файл - одна большая строка.
`-o` - выводить только совпавшее
`-a` - параметр z имеет ту особенность, что он считает, что файл бинарный. Поэтому, ничего не выведет. А вот `a` говорит, что выводи в любом случае.

в самой регулярке ещё две хитрости. `(?s)` - это указания, что бы . сопоставлялась с всеми символами. 
`.*?` - здесь знак вопроса - это выключение жадного режима.

Но по факту - поставьте себе ack. Он умеет все, что умеет grep, но заточен для программистов. Он умеет пропускать временные файлы, каталоги `.svn` и `.git` (и им подобные), автоматом рекурсивен. Та же задача на нем решается на порядок проще

```
ack '<head>(.*?)</head>' -o
```

Comment: Ух ты. И давно там perl-regex появились?

Comment: думаю, что они там уже давно. Там вообще то 4 типа регулярок есть.

Comment: Когда я последний раз смотрел man (точнее info) по grep, их там вроде не было. А грепов было три. Правда я затрудняюсь сказать, в каком веке это было

Comment: Судя по всему - с 2010 года (http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=9ecf17742ffe69de7ed8e96bbf3ecabccef12c75)

Comment: Я сижу с программы PowerGrep. С помощью нее получается нужно сделать (?s)<head>.*?</head>. А как добавить -Pzoa?

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что кроме одного общего слова в названии и похоже поведения, эти две программы больше не имеют ничего общего?

Comment: Спасибо большое, у меня получилось!!! Ура!!!